# Javascript event handler, RadTreeView: how to start actual action after some delay?

Tags: javascript, telerik

I have a RadTreeView, that displays a tree and method `onMouseOver` configured. Currently I need that some action is taken only in case if mouse remains over the RadTreeNode for about a second.

That is, how I modify this:

```
   function OnClientMouseOver(sender, args) {
       doSomeAjax();
   }
```

into: "if client is over the element for 1 second, `doSomeAjax()`";

I can also handle, of course, `OnClientMouseOut`, so if some delay-related process is started but client left the item, another event would terminate process.

Comment: no idea as to the specific implementation for your control, but you could wrap the code in a one second timer, and then ask whether the mouse is still on the element to run the ajax call (`setTimeout(function(){ if( /* mouse inside control */) { doSomeAjax(); } }, 1000);`

Comment: alternatively, you could add an `OnClientMouseOut` handler that cancels the operation. In this case, the code inside the timeout would clear said handler.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with setTimeout().

```
function ajaxFunction(){
    window.ajaxRequest = your ajax here;
}

$('.button').hover(
    function(){
        setTimeout(ajaxFunction(),'1000');
    },
    function(){
        //if mouse is out kill the ajax
        window.ajaxRequest.abort();
    }
);
```

hope this helps you